# Cross Compile GMP and Openswan for ARM on Ubuntu 12.04 32 Bit

Tags: compilation, open-source, arm, gmp, omap

I have to cross compile `opensawn` for a OMAP4 Board and GMP is prerequisite. First I tried it on 64 bit OS but it gave me this error:

> configure: error: Oops, mp_limb_t is 64 bits, but the assembler code in this configuration expects 32 bits.

Then I shifted to Ubuntu 12.04 32 Bit and the GMP V6.0.0 got compiled after few trials. Even after having the ARCH, TOOLCHAIN and CROSS_COMPILER variables in `.bashrc` I had to `export` the following:

```
export ARCH=arm<BR>
export PATH=/home/harsh32bit/Work/Projects/BSQ_VVDN/BISQUARE/gcc-SourceryCodeBenchLite-arm/bin/:$PATH<BR>
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-<BR>
```

Then following commands were observed:

```
./configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/home/harsh32bit/Work/Projects/BSQ_VVDN/BISQUARE/gcc-SourceryCodeBenchLite-arm/

make clean
make
make install
```

Then Soft-linking GMP Library to Toolchain

```
~/Work/Projects/BSQ_VVDN/BISQUARE/gcc-SourceryCodeBenchLite-arm/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.7.3  
# ln -s ~/Work/Projects/BSQ_VVDN/packages/gmp-6.0.0/.libs/libgmp.so libgmp.so
```

I had the GMP compiled successfully although the `make check` reported all test failed.

```
9 of 9 tests failed.
```

Now when I try to cross compile Openswan-2.6.41 after making changes in CROSSCOMPILE.sh and do this `make programs` I get this error:

> In file included from /home/harsh32bit/Work/Projects/BSQ_VVDN/packages/openswan-2.6.41/include/certs.h:24:0,from /home/harsh32bit/Work/Projects/BSQ_VVDN/packages/openswan-2.6.41/lib/libopenswan/id.c:42:
>       /home/harsh32bit/Work/Projects/BSQ_VVDN/packages/openswan-2.6.41/include/secrets.h:20:41: fatal error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
>       compilation terminated

I have gone to TI E2E site for this, sniffed internet for pointers in last 4 weeks but I couldn't figure out. If anyone has any clue about cross compiling `openswan` and `GMP` for ARM please advise me.

Comment: To paraphrase that error message, did the changes you made include adding the location of the GMP headers to the relevant include path(s)?

Comment: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.7.3/`
Do you mean this?

Comment: No, that points the linker to the cross-compiled C _libraries_. I mean telling the compiler where the _headers_ are, either with the  `-I <path>` option on the compiler command line, or using the [`CPATH` or `*_INCLUDE_PATH`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html) environment variable.

Comment: I used it with `make programs` but to no avail. Should I do it with some other command?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So essentially

- The static linkage of gmp files had to be done sans `sudo` - since when you call `make programs` from openswan package without `sudo` you are not root instead a normal user and if you use `make programs` with `sudo` it misses some exported variables particularly `ARCH`. It takes the default architecture instead of target architecture you want to compile for; like in my case it was for `arm`.
- If you have to use the `sudo`, make it readable-writeable for all. That is after linking the library files in the toolchain you can call `chmod 777` on that file - because then it will be available for rw for all user groups.

Comment: 777? Whut? Why would people need write access to the library?

Comment: Thats right, but while debugging which happen over a month being a newbie in linux, just to make sure that any user is able to execute it I made it that way.

Comment: This cannot possibly be a solution to the missing header file.